# JavaScript ajax call: how to return a value in if statement

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function in which, if idType is 1, I do a ajax call to my php file, in which I get the name with specific idName and return it. If idType is not 1, return another exemple value.

```
function get_name(idName, idType){
   var resultString = ""
   if(idType == 1){
       
       $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"myFile.php",
           dataType:"JSON",
           data:{idName: idN},
           success: function(data){
              resultString = data.name 
              console.log(resultString)
              return resultString   
           },
           error: function(d){
           
           }
       });

   } else {  
       resultString =  "otherValueName" 
       console.log(resultString)
       return resultString
   }
}
```

I have this function that takes as parameter some id names, and calls get_name with that specific idName and type. In this exemple function, I omitted the for cicle

```
function printName(exempIdName){
    var string= get_name(exempIdName, 1);
    console.log(string)
    return string
}
```

Finaly, I print the name

```
printName("Alex");
```

But if idType is 1 and does ajax call, the result is undefined. In the console, the result of variable "string" in printName function is undefined. But the result of the variable "resultString" in get_name has the right value.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one simple approach to achieve what you want. Just mark the ajax call to sync. By default, the jQuery Ajax call runs in Async mode, but we can make it run in Sync mode by passing "async: false" as one more argument.
**Here is the working copy of the solution**: Way1- We should return the promise from the function and then handle the promise to get result. Way2 - using async: false

1. HTML 2. JSON sample data (data.son)

   ```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                function get_ContentWay1(idName, idType) {
                    var resultString = ""
                    if (idType == 1) {
                        return $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "data.json",
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            data: { idName: idName },
                            success: function (data) {
                                resultString = data.employee.name;
                                console.log(resultString)
                            },
                            error: function (d) {

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        resultString = "otherValueName"
                        console.log(resultString)
                        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                            resolve(resultString);
                        });
                    }
                }




                function get_ContentWay2(idName, idType) {
                    var resultString = ""
                    if (idType == 1) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "data.json",
                            async: false,//You need to pass this
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            data: { idName: idName },
                            success: function (data) {
                                resultString = data.employee.name;
                                console.log(resultString)

                            },
                            error: function (d) {

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        resultString = "otherValueName"
                        console.log(resultString)
                    }
                    return resultString;
                }

                $("button.btnWay1").click(function () {
                    var idType = $(this).attr("idType");
                    var idName = $(this).attr("idName");

                    // Way 1
                    var contect = get_ContentWay1(idName, idType).then((result) => {
                        if (result != "otherValueName")
                            $("#div1").html(result.employee.name);
                        else
                            $("#div1").html(result);
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        alert("error");
                    });
                });

                $("button.btnWay2").click(function () {
                    var idType = $(this).attr("idType");
                    var idName = $(this).attr("idName");

                    //Way 2
                    var contect = get_ContentWay2(idName, idType);
                    $("#div1").html(contect);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="div1">
            <h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2>
        </div>

        <button class="btnWay1" idType="1" idName="abc">Get External Content Way 1</button>
        <button class="btnWay1" idType="2" idName="abc">Don't Get External Content Way 1</button>

        <button class="btnWay2" idType="1" idName="abc">Get External Content Way 2</button>
        <button class="btnWay2" idType="2" idName="abc">Don't Get External Content Way 2</button>

    </body>

    </html>
   ```

---

```
        {  
        "employee": {  
            "name":       "sonoo",   
            "salary":      56000,   
            "married":    true  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: "just make your Ajax call sync" is never the answer.

Comment: I've tried, but the result is always undefined. And in the console there is this message: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Comment: Yes, it's true, we are not supposed to make sync calls in Ajax because it violates the soul of ajax. But JQuery has given the option to make sync calls. We can use it if it's utmost necessary.

Comment: ...which it is *absolutely not* in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your code:

```php
function get_name(idName, idType){
   var resultString = ""
   if(idType == 1){
       
       $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"myFile.php",
           dataType:"JSON",
           data:{idName: idN}, // Here you are passing idN instead of idName
           success: function(data){
              resultString = data.name 
              console.log(resultString)   
           },
           error: function(d){}
       });

   } else {  
       resultString =  "otherValueName" 
       console.log(resultString)
   }

    return resultString;
}
```

Comment: I didn't flag any comment or devoted you! I can't even devote you cause my points aren't enough!

Comment: Pointing out the typo would still be served better as a comment, since it is not the cause of the "problem" at hand...